# Error in Entity Framework in code first pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

When I try to execute the update-database command, I get the error:

> Foreign key 'FK_dbo.HomeWork_dbo.Students_StudentID' references invalid column 'ID' in referenced table 'dbo.Students'.

This is my homework class inherited by the parent class containing a few properties, like ID, etc.

```
public class HomeWork: Commons_Parent
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `Student` class inherited by the class `Person` which hold properties like `Name`, etc.

```
public class Student: Person
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public Class Std_Class { get; set; }

    public int Class_ID { get; set; }
    public List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Llazar here is the code

Comment: It would be better if you could share the error by editing your question.

Comment: @ichthyocentaurs thanks for your reply, i have shared the code if want more details plz let me know

Comment: @Muamber Khan Could you please share the update database command that you're running, for further investigation.

Comment: It would help if you add the last migration code

Comment: Read the error. It is telling you the issue. You are trying to Map StudentID to ID and ID doesn't exist. Either create ID on the Student table or map it to something else.